# ExpanderView port to Windows Store Universal App

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, expander, windows-phone-toolkit

As the title indicate, i'm trying to port ExpanderView from windows phone toolkit and use it with windows store universal app ie. WinRT. After re-writing all the necessary classes from Phone:Toolkit into my app, I just founded that the Header of the ExapnderView is neither showing in design mode or in debug mode.

Can't find out what is the problem with this. Is there anyone who tried the same thing and have a solution? I attached the the classes so you can take a look on it, if you can.

[Expander RT codeplex](https://expanderview.codeplex.com/)

Comment: your link no longer works. It may be helpful if you updated the link and/or posted in a more permanent location like Git or elsewhere. There seems to be a ton of interest in this, so even putting the full source in your answer below for both Win and WP would help many folks out. Cheers!

Comment: @ToddMain I'm working on that. Been busy lately. It will be online in 2 Days.

Comment: @ToddMain you can find the link in the answer.

Comment: wow, thanks so much for both your hard work in porting and in finding it a permanent home!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found out what the problem was. I missed the style xaml that targets the ExpanderView. If anyone is intresseted in this control for WinRT, both windows 8.1 or windows phone 8.1, please pm me and I will send you the files.

EDIT***
You can find the full Project in codeplex using this link [ExpanderRT](https://expanderview.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Send it to me, pls, jnixon@microsoft(.com)

Comment: If you could send them to ar-spam at outlook.com, that would be great.

Comment: You should post the answer here

Comment: @FactorMystic Check it now

Comment: I am facing same issue as described by this person in the link,can you please guide me ?
https://expanderview.codeplex.com/discussions/578084

Comment: Hello sir, the ExpanderRT is not working in UWP (Visual 2015 Universal App). How to do that...plz help.